# Not receiving notifications from SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

We have checked the boxes for getting the notifications/email but still not able to receive it from SonarQube.

The sonarqube is configured correctly and the same is verified by checking the Jenkins log console output.

Can anyone please suggest for this issue.

Comment: You'll have to be a little more detailed:
Which notifications? Which SonarQube version? and if you're talking about the issue notifaction: which scm plugin/version?

Comment: @Johnnei We are using the web version of SonarQube(Version 0.0.1-Snapshot). Once the build is done through Jenkins the notifications are generated containing the details like the "Major","Minor","critical" issues. We can check the same using sonarqube but our requirement is such that we need to get an automated mail having the same details. Please let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: At first I'd check the following three points on your SonarQube instance:
- Do you have a SCM plugin (ex. sonar-scm-git-plugin)?
- Are issues automatically assigned to the correct SonarQube user?
- Is your Mail configuration working within SonarQube?

Comment: in the administration, have you checked that your email configuration is correct? What is the version of SonarQube?